# Marklogic XCC ContentSource using JNDI

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi, marklogic

I'm trying to get a Marklogic ContentSource object loaded from Tomcat's context.xml using JNDI and Spring.

I'm using Tomcat 8.5, and Spring 2.5 (unfortunately)

I have added the following to context.xml in Tomcat

```
<Resource name="MLContentSource" auth="Container" type="com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSource"
factory="com.marklogic.xcc.jndi.ContentSourceBeanFactory" 
url="xcc://username:password@mymarklogic-server/DatabaseName"/>
```

And the following in my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="contentSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/MLContentSource"/>
</bean>
```

I have another bean declared in my applicationContext.xml that relies on the ContentSource bean. Its expecting a property to be set that is of type com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSource

```
<bean id="marklogicRepository" class="org.example.repository.ingestion.MarkLogicRepositoryImpl">
    <property name="contentSource" ref="contentSource" />
</bean>
```

The issue is that the contentSource bean is of type JndiObjectFactoryBean and not com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSource. Is there something I'm missing to get a proper ContentSource from the JndiObjectFactoryBean?

Comment: I haven't tried JNDI with XCC before, but I'd start by writing some custom code that runs in Tomcat and tries to get a ContentSource via JNDI manually. Then, modify the custom code to use a JndiObjectFactoryBean to get the ContentSource. If neither of those works, something's wrong with the Tomcat config. If those work - then it would seem to be an issue with how marklogicRepository is configured. Worst case, that bean could retrieve the "contentSource" bean itself from the Spring ApplicationContext and get the ContentSource from there.

Comment: Also, do you have to use JDNI? I'd lean towards constructing the ContentSource via a custom FactoryBean impl, which then gets config details via Spring properties. That should work fine in Spring 2.5, just need a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer IIRC to read properties in from some file.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the above code actually worked, my IDE was complaining about types but Spring will automatically cast the object stored inside JndiObjectFactoryBean to the target type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try XQJ?

https://github.com/cfoster/xqj-pool-example/blob/master/src/main/java/simple/WithJNDI.java

http://xqj.net/

The XQuery API for Java

```
A standard Java interface to XML DataSources which support XQuery 1.0.
The XQJ API is to XML Databases as the JDBC API is to Relational Databases.
Is a light-weight design and is very easy to pick up.
```